# This program take lot of time for execution

Tags: java, optimization

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    if(t<1 || t>100){System.exit(0);}
    ArrayList a=new ArrayList<>();         
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){ 
        String s=in.next().toString(); 
        String s2=in.next().toString();      
        int count=0;
        int first=Integer.parseInt(s);
        int last=Integer.parseInt(s2);
        if(first<1 || last>1000000000){System.exit(0);}
        for(int k=first;k<=last;k++){                    
                int sqrt =(int)Math.sqrt(k);
                if(sqrt*sqrt==k){count++;}                                     
        }
        a.add(count);
    }
    Iterator it=a.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(it.next());
    }        
}
}
```

In this program when i give big input, it takes lots of time to give output. Can someone tell me how to optimize this program.
this program is for finding square root number.
Input: The first line contains , the number of test cases T. T test cases follow, each in a new line. 
Each test case contains two space-separated integers denoting s and s2.

Sample Input

```
2
3 9
17 24
```

Sample output

```
2
0
```

big input:

```
35
465868129 988379794
181510012 293922871
395151610 407596310
481403421 520201871
309804254 776824625
304742289 566848910
267554756 828997506
387224568 926504395
244571677 871603971
444567315 582147918
334350264 342469009
400474096 410940967
488907300 943628573
26441071 801576263
182001128 267557939
115732998 974318256
192538332 862327048
45429427 307805497
358658006 842644090
92930998 431601473
231163983 893672132
275221547 298953978
351237326 981399371
484598992 985428966
103405553 529324202
37393469 768655346
30179914 482808626
208821550 538302223
154654533 791652309
68424067 854065374
246956110 517538724
51395253 876949418
57778758 368742600
227566632 606529208
```

Comment: what is a big input? everything greater  than 100 shold stop the program

Comment: @KevinEsche 14
465868129 988379794
181510012 293922871
395151610 407596310
481403421 520201871
309804254 776824625
304742289 566848910
267554756 828997506
387224568 926504395
244571677 871603971
444567315 582147918
334350264 342469009
400474096 410940967
488907300 943628573
26441071 801576263
182001128 267557939

Comment: well, doing 14 iterations and doing multiple million looping in there will lead to a slightly higher execution time...

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need to do this in a loop: there can only be `sqrt(1000000000)` perfect squares less than `1000000000`, which is about 30k numbers. Just enumerate them all once, and count them for the range you need.

Comment: Can you share the link of the problem?

Comment: Also, once you've found one perfect square, you can jump straight to the next: it's just `(1+sqrt)^2`. No need to check all the numbers in between.

Comment: @YashMehta Here Scanner is just use for taking input about finding number of sqaure in given range(s,s2).

Comment: @AndyTurner in this program i am counting the number of square integers between given range. So i have to check all number between given range

Comment: I agree with @AndyTurner . Essentialy, you could take `sqrt(first)`, round it up and add 1's until you get out of region. If this is not enough you could add some memoization.

Comment: You don't even need to iterate. You can look at sqrt(first) and sqrt(last) and calculate the answer directly. Details left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Also, this code isn't very good. Raw types, clumsy unnecessary explicit use of an iterator, and inconsistency between nextInt vs. next/parseInt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This method compute the number of square between two bounds:**

```
public static int squaredNumberInRange(int lowerBound, int upperBound){
    double lowerRoot = Math.sqrt(lowerBound);
    double upperRoot = Math.sqrt(upperBound);

    lowerRoot = Math.ceil(lowerRoot);
    upperRoot = Math.floor(upperRoot);

    int spread = (int)upperRoot - (int)lowerRoot + 1;

    return spread;
}
```

Complexity is O(1)